# Too many decimal points in number when expanding a macro

Tags: c, shell, configure

I have this macro defined in configure.ac:

```
AC_SUBST(LIBAVUTIL_VERSION)
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(LIBAVUTIL_VERSION, "$LIBAVUTIL_VERSION")
```

After running configure the macro is correctly escaped:

```
-DLIBAVUTIL_VERSION=\"55.78.100\"
```

When I run make I get the error in the subject on this line of code:

```
static gchar libavinfo[] = "libavutil: " LIBAVUTIL_VERSION;
```

Comment: Where precisely are you seeing `-DLIBAVUTIL_VERSION=\"55.78.100\"`?

Comment: Whether it's correctly escaped depends on how many layers of unescaping happen at execution time. Context matters to be able to read/interpret that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In Makefile. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How can I know that? Thanks for replying.

Comment: One thing you can do is to prefix the individual makefile line running the compilation with `set -x;`, which will tell the shell to log what it's doing in an unambiguous format.

Comment: Are you building this on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @cup Linux. I do not use windoze.

Comment: Why not use PACKAGE_VERSION?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use AC_CONFIG_HEADERS?  I cannot reproduce your issue, and the macro expands just fine.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No. I don't have it in the configure.ac file. So shall I just add AC_CONFIG_HEADERS then to have it working?

Comment: Don't know if it will fix the problem, but if you wind up with a good looking #define in `config.h`, you know the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I don't have **config.h** among the sources file.

Comment: The point of AC_CONFIG_HEADERS is that it will put the #defines in a header file for you instead of using -D to define them.  The traditional name (that you give as an argument to AC_CONFIG_HEADERS) is `config.h`.  You then #include "config.h" in all your source files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
```

Comment: Then try `AC_DEFINE(LIBAVUTIL_VERSION, "\"$LIBAVUTIL_VERSION\"")`.